# Server & Client Connections Using Sockets

Tags: android, kotlin

After tried to make a Reversi Game CLient/Server in TCP and build/running with out issues, I figured out, that once I make a move in one screen/emulator it doesnt appear the changes in the other, and the game itselfs is not equal.

```
private fun startComm(newSocket: Socket) {
    if (threadComm != null)
        return

    socket = newSocket

    threadComm = thread {
        try {
            if (socketI == null)
                return@thread

            connectionState.postValue(ConnectionState.CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED)
            val bufI = socketI!!.bufferedReader()

            while (state.value != State.GAME_OVER) {
                val message = bufI.readLine()  //Mensagem com a posicao
                val splitStr: List<String> = message.split(" ")
                val moveX = splitStr[0].toInt()
                val moveY = splitStr[1].toInt()
                changeOtherMove(moveX,moveY)
            }
        } catch (_: Exception) {
        } finally {
            stopGame()
        }
    }
}
```

Opponent Player  Move Function:

```
private fun changeOtherMove(moveX: Int, moveY : Int) {
    //presenter.onClickPlace(moveX,moveY)

    otherMoveX = moveX
    otherMoveY = moveY
    state.postValue(State.PLAYING_ME)
    //checkIfSomeoneWins()
}
```

Current Player move:

```
fun changeMyMove(moveX: Int, moveY : Int) {
    if (connectionState.value != ConnectionState.CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED)
        return
    //presenter.onClickPlace(moveX,moveY)
    myMoveX = moveX
    myMoveY = moveY
    socketO?.run {
        thread {
            try {
                val printStream = PrintStream(this)
                printStream.println("$moveX $moveY")
                printStream.flush()
            } catch (_: Exception) {
                stopGame()
            }
        }
    }
    state.postValue(State.PLAYING_OTHER)
    //checkIfSomeoneWins()
}
```

Run move:

```
placeList = arrayOfNulls<List<ImageView>>(boardSize)
    .mapIndexed { x, list ->
        arrayOfNulls<ImageView>(boardSize).mapIndexed { y, imageView ->
            val place = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_place, null)
            place.setOnClickListener {
                            presenter.onClickPlace(x, y)
                            model.changeMyMove(x,y)}
            val grid = findViewById<GridLayout>(R.id.gamePlacesGrid)
            grid.addView(place)
            place.findViewById(R.id.gamePlaceImageView) as ImageView
        }
    }
```